# Ubuntu 18.04 Apache2 Virtual Host is showing main website

Tags: networking, apache2, 18.04, dns

I am attempting to make a subdomain for my website and I have created a virtual host, when I access the website subdomain.mydomain.com It show the same page as mydomain.com. Below is my virtual host.

```
<VirtualHost subdomain.mydomain.com:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain
ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com
ServerAlias www.subdomain.mydomain.com
<Directory "/var/www/subdomain">
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is placed in a separate virtual host file I have read a few other topics on here that say place it in the default host file, after trying that I am still having the same issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more research I have found out that my virtual host was setup wrong below is the virtual host that worked for me.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
        #referring the user to the recipes application
        DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain
        ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com

        <Directory /var/www/subdomain>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
                # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
                #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```